# Flex app behaves differently on Chrome, Firefox

Tags: apache-flex, flash, timer, cross-browser, frame-rate

My Flex app seems to have different frame rates in Chrome and Firefox. I have a preloader that is essentially a splash screen that fades away with a Timer, and it is this part that has the noticeable frame rate difference--it fades away faster in Firefox. The odd thing is that any Timers I'm using in the rest of the app seem to behave uniformly across browsers. It's only this preloader/splash screen that has the frame rate difference.

Is there something inherent in the way Chrome or Firefox deals with Flash that is causing this issue? Or is it the way I have set up my app with a preloader? I've reinstalled Flash, and both browsers are running 10.1, which promised to fix issues dealing with Timers and browser cross-compatibility.

This is really bugging me; any help or info would be appreciated!

Comment: Animations should usually be time-based, not frame-based.

Answer (score 0):

Max Frame Rate limitations can vary across browsers.  There is more information in this [blog post](http://www.kaourantin.net/2006/05/frame-rates-in-flash-player.html), although the information is a bit dated.  To quote:

> . In Internet Explorer this is 100 frames/sec. Why? Because the minimum time slice Windows timers can provide is 10 milliseconds. What about FireFox? FireFox does not use special timers and made a decision to limit the maximum frame rate for plugins. Why? The thinking is that users constantly complain that plugins take too much CPU time.

I couldn't find any specific information on Frame Rates for Chrome or Safari.  That said, are you sure you aren't have issues with load / rendering time in different browsers, as opposed to a frame rate mismatch?

Comment: Hmm, good point with the loading. Firefox does load the actual app faster as well. I switched my custom preloader with the default one, and this is evident; however, I have a Timer that fades in my main content, and this is also noticeably faster on FF. 

I'm not sure if it's a max frame rate problem; my app is at the default 24.

Comment: I don't understand how you're using a timer to fade in your main content.  Wouldn't you be better off using something like the show effect on the Application tag?  http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#effect:showEffect